# conditionally merge files by appending in bash

Tags: linux, bash, file

I have two files and would like to merge them - by appending to the last line.

file1.txt content

```
gitTrial 161 1.5 154.5 2 0 161 154.5 1.5
Yahoo 122 0.5 120.5 2 0 122 120.5 0.5
Stack 122 0.5 120.5 2 0 122 120.5 0.5
```

file2.txt content

```
 gitTrial 90
 Yahoo    91
```

Desired outcome - file3.txt

```
gitTrial 161 1.5 154.5 2 0 161 154.5 1.5 90
Yahoo 122 0.5 120.5 2 0 122 120.5 0.5 91
Stack 122 0.5 120.5 2 0 122 120.5 0.5 0
```

How do I go about this, please?

Note, zero is in place for null in the Stack line.

Comment: [`join`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html) the files. Remember to `-a` and set `-e 0`

Comment: @KamilCuk, I used, `join -a 1 -e 0 file1.txt file2.txt` is that correct? the 0 on the Stack line isn't there? I'd like to use join if possible. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR{ a[$1]=$2; next }
  { print $0, ($1 in a ? a[$1] : 0) }
' file2.txt file1.txt > file3.txt
```

When `file2.txt` is read, store field2 in array `a` using field1 as index.
When `file1.txt` is read, print the line plus the value of array `a` at index of field1 if present or `0` otherwise.
Redirect output to `file3.txt`.

Comment: Not sure why folks are voting down without explanation, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
join -11 -21 -a1 -e0 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2.2 <(sort -k1 file1.txt) <(sort -k1 file2.txt)
```

Comment: thanks. that's a lot more complicated than I had hoped